# Sliding div panel goes back on clicking buttons inside div panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using this code to slide my div from right on (button_panel) button click, everything is working fine but when I click any button inside div panel the panel goes back to its original position. It shouldnt happen because the click event is used only for button_panel. Any idea why ?

```
var sipPos = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button_panel").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#panel").animate({ right: sipPos }, 300, 'linear', function () {
            if (sipPos == 0) { sipPos = -150; }
            else { sipPos = 0; }
        });
    });
});

<div id="panel" style=" border-style: solid; border-color: #008000; background-color:#D5FFD5; width:150px; height:400px; right:-150px; top:142px; position:absolute" align="center" >
    <asp:ImageButton ID="button_panel" runat="server"  style=" background-image: url('images/ProgressBar1.jpg'); width:80px; height:30px; left:-83px;  margin-top:-12px; position:absolute; top:0px" Font-Bold="True" ImageUrl="~/images/green_left_arrow_104.jpg" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" style="margin-top:5px"  Text="Timer" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="margin-top:5px" Text="AFK!" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" style="margin-top:5px" Text="REVIEW" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of HTML too please?

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons fire a click to all of their parent elements, including the panel.  In other words, events bubble up through the DOM tree.

You need to do `e.stopPropagation()` in a handler for your buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button_panel").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#panel").animate({ right: sipPos }, 300, 'linear', function () {
            if (sipPos == 0) { sipPos = -150; }
            else { sipPos = 0; }
        });
    });

    $("#button_panel button").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();  // ADD THIS
    });
});
```

The assumption is that you actually have `button` elements.  Otherwise, put in `a` if you are using links.  Or if you have both do:

```
$("#button_panel button,a").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/RDKn6/

Comment: I have tried it, it doesnt work. I think it has something to do with postback. What do you reckon ?

Comment: Sorry, my original code was wrong.  I had it backwards in my head.  Did you try the code in my latest edit, adding a separate handler to your buttons?  See my demo code.  It would also help to see your HTML.

Comment: I am talking about the other buttons inside the div panel that I have put, if i click them the panel goes back. I have tried return false on click with those buttons and it works but it wont perform the click function then. Lets say if i want to put exit button in the panel and if i put return false on click event then the button performs no function.

Comment: Don't return false on them, then.  That prevents them from doing their default behavior.  Instead, just do like my first example and use `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Do I have to do that for every button in the panel ? If yes, how do i do that ?

Comment: Yes and no... What is the html for your buttons?  If they are all buttons, you just need one call: `$("#button_panel button").click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); })` will take care of all of the buttons in your panel.

Comment: It works in my example.  Instead of posting the ASP code, could you post the HTML that is generated by ASP?

Comment: No, you posted your ASP tags (`<asp:ImageButton>`).  This gets turned into actual HTML (`<button><img>`, etc) by the server, which is what the JavaScript acts on.  I don't know ASP well enough to figure out what your rendered HTML is.  If you open your page and then "view source" and copy the relevant piece of that, it would be more helpful.